# Register type conditionally in Autofac

Tags: c#-4.0, dependency-injection, autofac-module

I have parent class Animal and two child classes Dog and cat. I am using Autofac for dependency injection.  I want to register Dog and Cat based on condition that is specified in config file.

I want following code in my module class.

`If Dog mentioned in Config file then
builder.RegisterType<Dog>().As<Animal>().PropertiesAutowired().SingleInstance();
If cat mentioned in Config file then
builder.RegisterType<Cat>().As<Animal>().PropertiesAutowired().SingleInstance();`

Please suggest for same.

Comment: What's wrong with the logic as you have written it?

Comment: Is this write way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Animal"] == "Dog")
    builder.RegisterType<Dog>().As<Animal>().PropertiesAutowired().SingleInstance();

if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Animal"] == "Cat")
    builder.RegisterType<Cat>().As<Animal>().PropertiesAutowired().SingleInstance();
```

Comment: Can be resolve type at runtime ? If yesthen how will be do this?

Comment: @RashiGarg: I don't understand your question. Can you rephrase?

Comment: Suppose I had registered Dog class against animal by using following code. `builder.RegisterType<Dog>().As<Animal>().PropertiesAutowired().SingleInstance(); `   But at runtime if I want to register Cat then how will we do this without stopping application because at application startup Dog will be registered till application executing.

Comment: @RashiGarg: Changing the configuration during the application's lifetime is a really really bad practice. Instead of changing the registration, you register a 'composite animal'  that depends on both `Cat` and `Dog`, which allows you to switch them using some runtime condition.

Comment: Thanks but I have a confusion that If I register  a `composite animal` that depends on both `Cat` and `Dog` then Should I resolve it on the basis of condition ?

Comment: Can I keep my configuration into registry rather than config file ?

Comment: @RashiGarg: How do you intend to switch values during runtime? Please be aware that .NET will only read config values from the config file once and in ASP.NET, changing the config file will cause the application to restart.

Comment: I have created ASP.Net Web API and all configurations are in app.config not in Web.Config so I think if we change value in app.config then webAPI will not restart. Please confirm my understanding is correct or not.

Comment: @RashiGarg If you are hosting Web API inside IIS, IIS will absolutely restart your application. So your understanding is incorrect.

Comment: Thanks Stefen, Web API is hosted inside IIS so I will move all configurations from app.config to registry. So if i change in registry then WEb API will not restart.

Comment: @Stefen , Is there any other way to keep configuration settings for Web API apart from registry. My configuration settings contain database connection string which will be change at runtime and Web API should not be restart.

Comment: Why is it bad for you when the application restarts?

Comment: We have web api which is used to post data by customers across the globe. So if a user from NewYork posts data into database A should not be interruptted by user from London posting data into database B. We have this type of requirement. so web Api should not be restart. Please suggest if you have any thoughts for same.

Comment: In that case the connection string is not a configuration value; it's runtime data, since multiple requests can come in simultaneously that should operate on different databases.

Comment: Sorry I mixed two different requirements. We want to encrypt and decrypt our connection string so if we change web. config file to encrypt connection string our web API will restart that's why I thought app.config will be right choice but i think I will have to use registry.

Comment: Where you store thise connection strings seems irrelevant for your question. Your config should contain all connection strings that the application required for all its users. Now since the connection strings are runtime data, the following advice holds: https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=99

Comment: how can I use this piece of code ?   `builder.Register<CreditCard>(
  (c, p) =>
    {
      var accountId = p.Named<string>("accountId");
      if (accountId.StartsWith("9"))
      {
        return new GoldCard(accountId);
      }
      else
      {
        return new StandardCard(accountId);
      }
    });`   My requirement is something like this.